# How do I stub a function using oclif fancy-test in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have an oclif multi-command CLI I'm writing, the basic premise is I have a function which I am importing from an npm package I published which I want to stub during testing. Below is roughly what my command.js file looks like:

```
import {Command, flags} from '@oclif/command'
import {bar} from 'mypackage'

export default class Login extends Command {
  static flags = {...}

  static args = [...]

  async run() {

    cli.action.start('In progress...')
    await bar()
    cli.action.stop()

    this.log('Success')
  }
}
```

I want to stub the bar function which I am importing from mypackage during testing. The first thing I tried was the following which is based off https://github.com/oclif/fancy-test#stub

```
import {expect, test} from '@oclif/test'
import * as mypackage from 'mypackage'

describe('login', () => {
  test
  .stub(mypackage, 'bar', async () => 123)
  .stdout()
  .command(['mycommand'])
  .it('works', ctx => {
    expect(ctx.stdout).to.equal('Success')
  })
})
```

However, I get the following error when running yarn test:

```
TypeError: mypackage_1.bar is not a function
```

So I tried updating the import line in the command.js file as follows

```
// OLD
import {bar} from 'mypackage'
await bar()

// NEW
import * as mypackage from 'mypackage' // NEW
await mypackage.bar() // NEW
```

With this update, I get a very similar error when running yarn test:

```
TypeError: mypackage.bar is not a function
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, I followed the docs as shown for stubs, so at this point I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Where does the `cli` variable come from?